# Showing text from TextArea in Same formatting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textarea

I am using Asp.net MVC. I am getting some text from oracle database and this text has some formatting. it has some newline. when I post to server and again showing in the view it doesn't show the newline and spaces.
before this application was in oracle forms. it printed same like we stored in database.

[image: as seen in form]

in above picture we see the formatting of database which has some new lines. but when I post to the server and showing in the view again it doesn't have this formatting. 
Note: in database we don't have any special char save with this string
please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display it as preformatted text, which will preserve white space just enclose it in pre tag

```
<pre>
    @Model.Body
</pre>
```

Comment: thanks Bro. but it come in the box and also have the Scroller how to remove that box as will to hide scroller as will.

Comment: you can simply hide the scrolls with CSS overflow property overflow: hidden but this will hide the contents if you please paste your code

Answer (score 1):

The string may just have linefeed characters (`\n`) (also known as character 10) and these display as new lines in some applications, but not in others (for example when opened in Windows notepad, these characters will not show up at all)

To make the linefeeds show up as newlines in windows applications you need to replace "`\n`" with "`\r\n`"  (carriage-return plus linefeed).

```
value = value.Replace("\n","\r\n")
```

Alternatively, the problem could be that the text is being shown in a web browser, in which case you need to put html "Line Break" elements in, which are written like this "`<br />`"

```
value = value.Replace("\n","<br />\n")
```

Hopefully one of those approaches will help you.

More details about what's happening now would allow us to be more specific.